# bower register EMALFORMED error

Tags: package, bower

I am having an error when trying to register a bower package.

The error is unxepcted token :

And my bower.json is

```
  {
  "name": "cordova-meets-angular",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/RefineriaWeb/cordovaMeetsAngular",
  "description": "A JS Wrapper for cordova plugins to be used in Angular Mobile projects",
  "moduleType": [
    "globals"
  ],
  "dependencies":[
    "angular": "~1.2.23"
  ],
  "keywords": [
    "angular",
    "cordova",
    "plugins",
    "mobilejs"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": false,
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "test",
    "tests"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the dependencies field. You are using an array instead of a hash:

> **[dependencies](https://github.com/bower/bower.json-spec)**
>
> Type: Object
>
> Dependencies are specified with a simple hash of package name to a
>   semver compatible identifier or URL.

The *dependencies* field should be:

```
"dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.2.23"
},
```